# What is the difference between キミ and キミの事?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, anime

In songs and anime (yes, I know that they're not always good representations of normal spoken Japanese) I see キミの事 used (for example キミの事が大好き), and I'm pretty sure that it doesn't mean the literal translation of (I like your things/event/etc), and probably just means (I like you). Is there a distinction in the way it would be used in connection with "your"?

Edit: Aight, I see now. As for 事, it means "everything about [object]" in a very large sense, but without it, it's less strong. Of course this can mostly only be used with people and (maybe?) other ANIMATE objects. なるほどｗ、本当にありがとう!

Comment: When I first learned this construction, I laughed -- a literal translation of _"I like your thing"_ sounds really quite あやしい.   